# I can't run emulator in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

Here, some error occur when I run emulator for run application.

Answer (score 0):

Try building a new emulator device. If you are using API 30 device then try using API 29 one. Also don't download the latest Android, you can download the Android 10.

Make sure you have enough disk space where you are building the device.
Let me know if any of this helps!